# jmeter avoid proxy in one request

Tags: java, proxy, jmeter

I have a script in jmeter 5.1.1 where I define the proxy connection when opening it with commands.
I need the proxy in all the HTTP request, however I **need to avoid the proxy** in one specific HTTP request.

I tried to write something (space, null,...) in the HTTP Request to avoid proxy, however jmeter is always using the predefined proxy to access the HTTP Request, so the connection fails.

How can I avoid proxy settings? I don't want to set proxy in all the HTTP Requests, as there are lot of them.

I tried to use Java code with a pre-processor to edit the proxy settings, however the object sampler doesn't have the method SetProxyHost defined in the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setProxyHost-java.lang.String-).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct function name is `setProxyHost`, in Java they're very case sensitive.

---

1. Define proxy for all the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Samplers using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/), the settings live under "Advanced" tab

   [image]
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which needs to go without the proxy and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   sampler.setProxyHost('')
   ```
3. That's it, the sampler with the JSR223 PreProcessor will establish direct connection

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dmitri, however with jmeter 5.1.1 I always get a **MissingMethodException**: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.setProxyHost() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: []
Possible solutions: getProxyHost(), getProxyPass(), setProtocol(java.lang.String)

Comment: I just check that setProxyHost is in jmeter 5.2.1 but not in 5.1.1! Let me try again.

Comment: If you want to stay with JMeter 5.1.1 (although according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%e2%80%9cout-memory%e2%80%9d-failure/) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter) you can use this alternative code instead: `sampler.setProperty('HTTPSampler.proxyHost', '')`